# Issue with transforming datatable to well formatted JSON string

Tags: c#, javascriptserializer

The problem boils down to as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEaPj.png)

PS: The datatable structure is defined as above in the image.

I am using C# core to solve the problem of removing the '[' and ']' from each of datatable column values and would like to convert the same by serializing as JSON string first and the deseralize to create well formed XML construct.

The issue I am facing is that I want the column values under column name: 'XMLNodePath' as XML node tag and values under column name: 'XMLElementValue' as XML node value( XML construct should be wrapped at the start and at the end with   respectively i.e as shown in image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF6bG.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF6bG.png)

I have tried to achieve the same with below code but it is unable to achieve the same XML construct:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   row = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   if (dr.Field<string>("SecLegInd") != "")
   {
      dr.Field<string>("SecLegInd").Remove(1, 1);
      dr.Field<string>("SecLegInd").Remove(dr.Field<string> 
      ("SecLegInd").Length - 1, 1);
   }
   if (dr.Field<string>("XMLNodePath") != "")
   {
      dr.Field<string>("XMLNodePath").Remove(0, 1);
      dr.Field<string>("XMLNodePath").Remove(dr.Field<string> 
      ("XMLNodePath").Length - 1, 1);
    }
    if (dr.Field<string>("XMLElementValue") != "")
   {
      dr.Field<string>("XMLElementValue").Remove(0, 1);
      dr.Field<string>("XMLElementValue").Remove(dr.Field<string> 
      ("XMLElementValue").Length - 1, 1);
    }
    row.Add(dr.Field<string>("XMLNodePath"), dr.Field<string>("XMLElementValue"));
    rows.Add(row);
}
rows.Where(pair => pair.Count > 0)
                              .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Keys, pair => pair.Values);
string JSONstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows, new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
  NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
});
var temp = JArray.Parse(JSONstring);
temp.Descendants()
                .OfType<JProperty>()
                .Where(attr => attr.Value.ToString() == "")
                .ToList() 
                .ForEach(attr => attr.Remove());
 JSONstring = temp.ToString();
 xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode("{\"envelope\":" + JSONstring + "}", "envelope");
```

Please anyone let me know the thoughts on how to achieve the same.

Comment: what is the target t is the target framework in VS? is this .net core or .net standard? Is your project newly created or are you trying to upgrade? you can add `<PropertyGroup>
   <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>` to your project file if you are not targeting to .net5

Comment: Put your code inside a function. Does it then work?

Comment: Please let me know how to solve the mentioned problem